# S.M.A.R.T attribute saying FAILING_NOW

Tags: smart

I have the following SMART attribut staying at FAILING_NOW, but with a raw value of just 1. Is it not suposed to change to IN_THE_PAST later ?

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   099   099   099    Old_age   Always   FAILING_NOW 1
```

I already rebooted the machine a couple of times and it stay like that.
I would like to have it cleared because currently smartd is sending me email about that everyday, and I think it's because the status isn't at IN_THE_PAST.

Any idea ?

Cheers

Comment: This attribute generally indicates a [failure in the drive's electronics](https://kb.acronis.com/content/9119). It should be taken offline and replaced immediately, as it may be writing corrupt data to the drive.

Comment: One would think the phrase "failing now" to be self explanatory.  I'm curious as to what that status of a failing drive should say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is inside [smartctl man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/smartctl):

> If the Attribute's current Normalized value is less than or equal to
>   the threshold value, then the "WHEN_FAILED" column will display
>   "FAILING_NOW". If not, but the worst recorded value is less than or
>   equal to the threshold value, then this column will display
>   "In_the_past"

In short, your `VALUE` column has not recovered to a value above the threshold. Maybe your disk is really failing now (and each reboot cause some CRC error) or the disk firmware treats this kind of error as permanent and will *not* restore the instantaneous value to 0.